# JS print - CSS text color not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I'm making an invoice in HTML & CSS. The goal is that after filling in, the invoice gets printed. But for some reason it doesn't print the CSS color of text. All text is black.
All other CSS styling works, like `font-family`, `font-size`, `font-weight` ...

This is the original in HTML & CSS :

[image]

And this is what is printed :

[image]

The printing is done with js: `window.print();`

Does anyone know why CSS color isn't working?

EDIT:
the title is placed in a table with id `'factuur'`:

```
<td id="factuurTitel">Stukadoorwerken Vanhees Frank</td>
```

The title has this CSS:

```css
#factuurTitel {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #194197;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Carrois Gothic SC', Calibri, sans-serif;
}
```

I have this `@media print` :

```css
@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #factuur, #factuur * {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    @page {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding `#factuurTitel { color: #194197; }` to the `@media print`.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Usually JS Print only handles html content alone if you want to give stylings to print, Use separate media query print in your css file:

```
 @media print
   {
      /* your css goes here */
   }
```

Comment: I've tried a lot of things, I don't even know anymore. But all the styling is working except for the color..

Answer (score 1):

```
#factuur, #factuur * { 
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  color-adjust: exact;
}
```

This works in webkit browsers and the latest firefox updates, otherwise there's no other known solution.
I had the same problem myself.